# useEffect for using document in nextJs

Tags: next.js, document

I want to create simple game through the youtube video but i'm using nextJs instead of javascript & html , it seems that in nextJs we can not use `document.something` because nextJs doesn't render in browser, so i searched and realized that i should use document inside `useEffect` ,so i changed my code to:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


// const block = document.createElement('div')


function game() {

//     if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
//   // browser code
//     }   

    const blockWidth = 100
    const blockHeight = 20
    class Block {
        constructor (xAxis, yAxis){
        this.bottomLeft = [ xAxis, yAxis ]
        this.bottomRight = [ xAxis + blockWidth , yAxis ]
        this.topLeft = [ xAxis , yAxis + blockHeight ]
        this.topRight = [ xAxis + blockWidth , yAxis + blockHeight]
        }
    }

    const blocks = [ 
        new Block(10,270)
    ]
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')

        function addBlocks () {
            for (let index = 0; index < blocks.length; index++) {
                const block = document.createElement('div');
                block.classList.add('block')
                block.style.left = blocks[index].bottomLeft[0] + 'px'
                block.style.bottom = blocks[index].bottomLeft[1] + 'px'
                grid.appendChild(block)
                
            }
        
        }
        addBlocks()
        console.log("test");
      })

  return (
    <div className='grid' style={{"width":"600px","height":"300px","border":"solid white 1px","position":"absolute"}}>
      <div className='block' style={{"width":"100px","height":"20px","backgroundColor":"blue","position":"absolute","left":"50px","bottom":"50px"}}></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default game
```

But still doesn't work and doesn't create `block` for me.
Anyone knows why? Thanks.

I expect my useEffect create new `block` for me

Comment: This is an anti-pattern to React. Why do something like this when React can do it for you easily with JSX syntax. 

You can write something like this `{blocks.map(block => <div className="block" style={{ left: block.bottomLeft[0], bottom: block.bottomLeft[1] }} />}` inside the grid div to render all the blocks.

Comment: It didn't work, but if you explain how i can  solve it using useEffect, it could be better, i am curios to how to use document in useEffect